# Unresolved reference error raised when calling a generator in python

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I am writing a generator in python, this code works fine:

```
def gen(a, b):
    for i in itertools.count():
        if i % 2 == 0:
            yield a
        if i % 2 != 0:
            yield b


def main():
    x, y = 2, 1
    res = gen(x, y)  # gen = gen(x, y) would raise error
    print(list(next(res) for _ in range(10)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


>>
[2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

If I change `res` to `gen` in the `main()`, it raises an `Unresolved reference error`. But if I delete the `main()` and put `gen = gen(x, y)` under `if __name__ == '__main__':`, it works as fine:

```
def gen(a, b):
    for i in itertools.count():
        if i % 2 == 0:
            yield a
        if i % 2 != 0:
            yield b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gen = gen(2, 1)
    print(list(next(gen) for _ in range(10)))


>>
[2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

And I think `generator` in python is kind of `iterator` since they can be used in `next()`, then why can't we directly pass `gen(2, 1)` into `next()` as `print(list(next(gen(2, 1)) for _ in range(10)))`? This raises another error:
`'generator' object is not callable`

Comment: [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python) you can find explanation regarding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `main` function and have the line `gen = gen(x, y)` you get an error because you're reusing a variable name, changing a global variable into a local variable and it's getting confused. Basically when you declare `gen` inside the function it cancels out the global `gen` so now `gen()` doesn't exist. You can avoid this by not reusing a variable name or if you do want to reuse the name you can specify that you're importing the global variable `gen` like this:

```
def main():
    global gen
    x, y = 2, 1
    gen = gen(x, y)
    print(list(next(gen) for _ in range(10)))
```

More information about global and local variables can be found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Comment: When we create a function `foo()`, does python auto-generate a variable with the same name `foo` to store the reference of `foo()`? If that is the case, then why we can't get rid of `gen = gen(2, 1)` before `next(gen)`? Say, why the code should be like `gen = gen(2, 1) next(gen)`, rather than `next(gen)` or `next(gen(2, 1)`?

Comment: @SimonZ. Yes, when you create a function `foo()` that is itself a variable, it's something stored in that namespace under that name, so it will overwrite anything else with the name foo. But when you say why can't we get rid of etc, I don't understand what you're asking.